# Permutation representation of Quaternion group $Q_8$, What determines cycles elements are mapped to?

Tags: group-theory, quaternions, permutation-cycles

> Permutation representation of Quaternion group $Q_8$, What determines cycles elements are mapped to?

So I made a permutation representation of $Q_8$ acting on itself where I labeled the elements $1=1,2=-1,3=i,4=-i,5=j,6=-j,7=k,8=-k$

And then figured out the permutation representation as elements of $S_8$ and I noticed that the cycle types of elements came out different. I expected that $i,j,k$ should all be products of two $4-$cycles after I did $i$, $\sigma_i=(1324)(5768)$

but instead $j$ gets mapped to a $4-$cycle and two $2$ cycles.

$\sigma_j=(1526)(48)(37)$

> My question is just why does this happen? Is there something which determines what kind of cycle you get from an element in the image of a permutation representation?

Comment: Apparently you multiply by $j$ from the right. Then it goes $1\mapsto j\mapsto -1\mapsto -j\mapsto 1$ and $i\mapsto k\mapsto -i\mapsto -k\mapsto i$. In the latter 4-cycle $ij=k$, $kj=-i$, $-ij=-k$, $-kj=i$.

Comment: The cycles must all have the same length, because in any group we have the cancellation law. If multiplication by $g$ gives a 2-cycle: $a\mapsto b\mapsto a$ with $b=ag$ and $a=bg$, then $ag^2=a$ implying that $g^2=1$ by the cancellation law.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I computed $\sigma_j$ incorrectly it should be $(1526)(3847)$. I see what you're saying I think with how $-1$ gets represented by $(12)(34)(56)(78)$. The way the element acts on other elements forms disjoint cycles, which get shown in the permutation representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't calculate $\sigma_j$ correctly.  Since $j$ has order 4, $\sigma_j$ must be the product of 4-cycles.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Its actually $(1526)(3847)$. Why does it have to be a product of $4$-cycles? The order of a $4$-cycle with two $2$ cycles is also order $4$.

Comment: @AColoredReptile If you have $ax^2=a$ then $x^2=1$ so the element $x$ which generates a $2-$cycle of any kind must have order $2$ (order $1$ would be the identity)

Comment: @MarkBennet Ok. Does that mean if I have a symmetric group acting on itself, like say $(123)(45)\in S_5$, then since it has order $6$, it should be a product of $6$ cycles? So essentially whatever the element is, it's order determines the length of the cycles, and the order of the group divided by the order of the element determines how many cycles are in the product?

Comment: @AColoredReptile That is correct.

Comment: @AColoredReptile That is indeed how $S_5$ acts on the $120$ elements of the group.